# allure. не находит allure-maven-plagin и allute-testng-adaptor

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, allure

**pom-файл** такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <artifactId>1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                <argLine>-Dmaven.browser</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <argLine>-Dmaven.browser</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>LATEST</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

**mvn clear test site** пишет следующие:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>
> [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the
>   POMs:
>
> [ERROR] Malformed POM
>   C:\Users\astaninama\IdeaProjects\untitled\pom.xml: Unrecog nised tag:
>   'dependency' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n\n        ... @10:21)  @
>   C:\Users\astaninama\IdeaProjects\untitled\pom.xml, line 10 , column 21
>
> [ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefi re-plugin must be a valid
>   version but is 'LATEST'. @ line 56, column 18
>
> [ERROR] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.artifactId' is missing. @ line 40,
>   column 13  @
>
> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR]   The project 1:1:1.0
>   (C:\Users\astaninama\IdeaProjects\untitled\pom.xml ) has 3 errors
>
> [ERROR]     Malformed POM
>   C:\Users\astaninama\IdeaProjects\untitled\pom.xml: Unr ecognised tag:
>   'dependency' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n\n        <
>   dependency>... @10:21)  @
>   C:\Users\astaninama\IdeaProjects\untitled\pom.xml, lin e 10, column 21
>   -> [Help 2]
>
> [ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-su refire-plugin must be a valid
>   version but is 'LATEST'. @ line 56, column 18
>
> [ERROR]     'reporting.plugins.plugin.artifactId' is missing. @ line
>   40, column 13
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e swit ch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please rea d the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
>   gException
>
> [ERROR] [Help 2]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseExce ption

Почему не находит `allure-maven-plagin` и `allute-testng-adaptor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ошибка не несуществующих пакетов, это ошибка целостности pom.xml. Если вы откуда-то копировали содержимое pom, скорее всего в него попали непечатные символы, из-за которых происходят ошибки. Попробуйте вручную переписать секцию dependencies, потому что с т.з. синтаксиса все выглядит нормально, и тег dependency, на котором все ломается - вполне легальный.

Кроме того, в pom.xml есть следующие ошибки:

- секция plugins должна входить в секцию build
- aspectj.version должен быть указан в секции properties

После их исправления проект успешно заводится

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <artifactId>1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
      <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
          <configuration>
          <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
          <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
          <properties>
              <property>
              <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
              <value>false</value>
              </property>
              <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
              </property>
          </properties>
          <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
          <argLine>-Dmaven.browser</argLine>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.16</version>
          <configuration>
          <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
          <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
          </argLine>
          <properties>
              <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
              </property>
          </properties>
          <argLine>-Dmaven.browser</argLine>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
              <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>LATEST</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: попробовала, но ошибки остались :(

Comment: @mariatest я попробовал скопировать целиком ваш pom.xml, внести небольшие правки (см. обновленный ответ), и проект у меня успешно собрался

Comment: действительно, проект успешно собрался, правда есть несколько предупреждений. однако секция 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId> <version>${aspectj.version}</version> </dependency> подчеркнута красным

Comment: @mariatest секция properties была добавлена? что выводит при наведении?

Comment: properties была добавлена как в ответе выше. при наведении пишет, что такая зависимость не найдена

Comment: аналогично с allute-testng-adaptor

Comment: @mariatest если в выводе maven не содержится сообщений о том, что они не были найдены - все в порядке, это значит что idea по тем или иным причинам их не видит, но maven нормально собирает

Comment: [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
1:1:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found d
uplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin @
line 49, column 21
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.

Comment: [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[WARNING] Results directory for module 1 not found.
[WARNING] Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories foun
d.

Comment: только такие WARNING

Comment: видимо поэтому не добавляются аннотации к тестам, такие как Title, Description, Test

Comment: @mariatest это сравнительно безопасные предупреждения, сами артефакты он грузит нормально. У вас дважды объявлен maven-surefire-plugin, вам нужно оставить только одно объявление, объединив конфигурацию. Аллюр не отрабатывает, потому что не собираются результаты тестов (возможно, из-за двойного объявления плагина).

Comment: все таки аллюр не обрабатывается не потому что было двойное объявление плагина. буду разбираться в чем дело. спасибо!!!